# Placement of filter capacitors in a circuit with multiple audio outputs

Tags: capacitor, audio, filter, output

I have a multiple output stage of an audio circuit as in the picture attached.
I want to add a capacitor to eventually filter any DC at the output, therefore I placed a RC filter 10uF/100k(0,16 HZ) for every single output.
This is OPTION1 in the picture.

I was wondering why i couldn't place a single RC filter before splitting the signal instead.
This is OPTION2 in the picture.
Is there any reason why that wouldn't be a solution?

The only point i see is that if any of the output, for any reason, would generate a DC voltage, then I couldn't filter it.. But this would not likely happen.

Any advice or observation on this?
[image]

Comment: What power rails are used by the op-amps? Do the outputs ever clip? What input offset voltage spec is the op-amp? How small can the output DC level be before you regard it as insignificant? R14, R15 and R16 are not needed.

Comment: The question is generic is not related to this exact circuitry.
In this circuit shown the power supply is bipolar. 
I'm not talking about problems with clipping. Is this information relevant?
input offset could be 0.5mV as for the NE5532 and i would say that 4mV is the maximum acceptable

Comment: The question isn't generic; it shows a specific circuit and, as always (and usual with electronics) the devil is in the detail <-- this means we need a circuit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The circuits are in the image posted

Answer (score 1):

You can place an RC filter at the input, but its behaviour would depend on the input impedances of each of the stages attached to it. R3 and R5, for example, form an impedance \$R_X\$ to DC which must be accounted for:

$$ R_X = 5.6k\Omega + 5.6k\Omega = 11.2k\Omega $$

Then you also have R11, which is another 5.6kΩ to DC (IC3's virtual ground in this case). Combined, R3, R5 and R11 present impedance \$R_T\$ to ground:

$$ R_T = R_X \parallel R_{11} = \frac{11.2k\Omega \times 5.6k\Omega}{11.2k\Omega + 5.6k\Omega} = 3.7k\Omega $$

Resistor R25 in your input RC filter appears in parallel with \$R_T\$, and is redundant. You can remove it, and size capacitor C7 according to this already-present \$R_T\$. Assuming you want a cut-off frequency of 10Hz:

$$ C_7 = \frac{1}{2\pi R_T f} = \frac{1}{2\pi \times 3.7k\Omega \times 10Hz} = 4.3\mu F$$

If you don't use an input filter, any DC offset at the input is more likely to cause that signal to fall outside the op-amps' permissible input range. If you had higher gains in those amplifiers, that input DC offset could saturate the op-amp outputs, causing clipping, and no amount of DC filtering at their outputs can fix that.

Since each individual amplifier in your circuit has ground-referenced input *and* output, using a common input filter would remove DC from all outputs, with the exception of any output offset introduced by the op-amps themselves.

IC1 and IC3 are configured for unity gain, and output offset would be equal to the input offset voltage for the op-amp, which could be anywhere from tens of microvolts to many millivolts, depending on the op-amp model. IC2 is configured with a gain of 2, and would produce twice that. If these output offsets are unacceptably large, then individual RC filters at each output will eliminate them.

All things considered, perhaps it's best to have filters at both input and outputs.

Also, R14, R15 and R16 serve no purpose if there are no capacitors accompanying them.